# Has the inclination of the orbital plane of Phobos and Deimos followed that of Mars' axial tilt?

Tags: mars, orbital-elements, phobos, deimos

Phobos and Deimos are very close to Mars' equatorial plane (the inclination of their orbits is roughly 1°). The axial tilt of Mars has changed a lot over time, and might have had a inclination of over 60° compared to the ecliptic at times.

Did the inclination of Phobos and Deimos also change over time, following the axial tilt of Mars (and if so, by what mechanism?)? Or have the equator of Mars and the orbits of Phobos and Deimos lined up at the present time by chance?